# How to access methods in a class file in Java with a Public Interface?

Tags: java, interface, instantiation, object-files

In Eclipse I have a public interface called RotationCipher, I am given an object file that implements this interface and contains crypto methods without the .java files. How do I access these methods in the class file from my class and use this already compiled code in my program.

I can't seem to find much on Google when I search for this question.

All help will be very much appreciated :)

Comment: if the source code is not available decompile it, but be aware of its licence

Comment: Is that a single .class file or a jar file?

Comment: Hi it's a single class file that I've been given for a school project and I have to be able to access the methods without a .java file. I was given a public interface, but I can't seem to instantiate the object as you would with an ordinary class file.

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse, you have to add the .class or .jar file to the Project -> Properties -> Java build path. In your class .java file, you have to import the contained class(es). And of course, you have to read the javadoc of the imported class, where you find the provided public methods.

Comment: Or you can look at the provided interface, since the class does not have a JavaDoc or source attachment.